# How to affect contents of a div

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<span class = "Box">
<div class = "active">
<a href ="#-night">
<span class ="list">4</span>
<span class="locations"><?php echo $location; ?></span>
<span class="type">Night </span>
</a>        
</div>
</span>
```

CSS

```
.Box {
white-space: nowrap;
padding: 0px 20px;
font-size: 110%;
color: blue;}

.list {
height: 30px;
width: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px; /* or 50% */
border-radius: 15px; /* or 50% */
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
background-color: orange;
color: blue;} 

.locations{
text-transform: uppercase;
color: blue;}

.type {
text-transform: uppercase;
color: blue;}
```

I want the .active span to change the font color of .list , .locations and .type to dark blue or any other color
I'm no expert at CSS and looking online hasn't given me any answers.
Apologies if I am posting this wrong or am asking stupid questions.

Comment: where is div in your code??

Comment: sorry, i don't have it yet but was thinking of changing span "active" to div "active" if that makes any difference

Comment: Edit the question to and remove the php tag . before it gets voted down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.active .list,
.active .locations,
.active .type {
    color: darkBlue;
}
```

Example...

```css
.Box {
white-space: nowrap;
padding: 0px 20px;
font-size: 110%;
color: blue;}

.list {
height: 30px;
width: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px; /* or 50% */
border-radius: 15px; /* or 50% */
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
background-color: orange;
color: blue;} 

.locations{
text-transform: uppercase;
color: blue;}

.type {
text-transform: uppercase;
color: blue;}

.active .list,
.active .locations,
.active .type {
    color: darkBlue;
}
```

```html
<span class = "Box">
<div class = "active">
<a href ="#-night">
<span class ="list">4</span>
<span class="locations"><?php echo $location; ?></span>
<span class="type">Night </span>
</a>        
</div>
</span>
```

Comment: this was way too easy haha, don't know how i didn't think of that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add this -:

```
a {
    color :red; // your color here
  }
```

and remove the attribute color from the other selector.